# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Unknown command

Tags: mysql, websphere

I'm trying to create datasource for connection pooling mysql database in Websphere Application Server.

I've set the JDBC Provider, I set the

```
Implementation class name   : com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource
```

my mysql driver version is 5.1.6.

but I got this error while I try to connect the datasource:

```
The test connection operation failed for data source btn_itb_ds on server server1 at node qnode with the following exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Unknown command. View JVM logs for further details.
```

I have read this http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=38388 trouble shooting. But they just suggest to upgrade mysql driver version 5.1.X and I have do that. but I've got the same error.

Comment: It helps if you post the JVM logs as that would contain information on the error.